# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined when trying to upload image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer, cloudinary

TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined when trying to upload image. This error is driving me crazy! I can upload images with no issues when I use POSTMAN but when I go to upload an image via the web app I get the error above. I have triple checked everything and can not seem to find the issue. I know there are a lot of question with the same topic to which I have read all of and not found one single solution to my problem.

```
BACKEND======================================================================================
userRouter.post('/property', parser.single('propertyImage'),passport.authenticate('jwt',{session : false}),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.file);
//    const result =  cloudinary.uploader.upload(
//     req.file.path)
//     console.log(result)
    
    const property = new Property({
        street: req.body.street,
        town: req.body.town,
        area: req.body.area,
        PostCode: req.body.PostCode,
        NoBeds: req.body.NoBeds,
        NoBath: req.body.NoBath,
        NoLivingRooms: req.body.NoLivingRooms,
        askingPrice: req.body.askingPrice,
        propertyImage: req.file.path
        
    });

     property.save(err=> {
        if(err)
         res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody: "Error has occured", msgError : true}});
        else{
            req.user.properties.push(property);
            
            req.user.save(err=> {
                if(err)
                 res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody: "Error has occured", msgError : true}});
                 else
                
                 res.status(200).json({message: {msgBody: "Successfully created property", msgError : false}});
            })
        }
    })
});

MULTER AND CLOUDINARY SETTINGS=====================================================
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;


cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
});

module.exports = cloudinary;

const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
 
const app = express();
 
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: {
    folder: 'propertyImages',
    format: async (req, file) => 'png', // supports promises as well
    public_id: (req, file) => 'computed-filename-using-request',
  },
});
 parser = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = parser
 


FRONTEND===============================================================================
 import React, {useState,useContext} from 'react'
import PropertyItem from './PropertyItem';
import PropertyService from '../Services/PropertyService';
import Message from './Message'
import {AuthContext} from '../Context/AuthContext';
import '../stylesheets/Property.css'

const Properties = props =>{
    const [property,setProperty] = useState({
        // propertyImage: "",
        street : "",
        town : "",
        area : "",
        PostCode : "",
        NoBeds : "",
        NoBath : "",
        NoLivingRooms : "",
        askingPrice: "",
    })
    const [propertyImage,setPropertyImage] = useState ([]);
    const [message,setMessage] = useState(null);
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

    const onSubmit = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const formData= new FormData();
        formData.append('propertyImage', propertyImage);
                    PropertyService.postProperty(property, formData).then(data =>{
            const {message } = data;
            resetForm();
            if(message.msgBody === "UnAuthorized"){
                setMessage(message);
                authContext.setUser({username : ""});
                authContext.setIsAuthenticated(false);
            }
            else{
                setMessage(message);
            }
        },[]);
    }

    const onChange = e =>{
        setProperty({...property,[e.target.name] : e.target.value})
    }
    const onChangeFile = e =>{
         setPropertyImage(e.target.files[0])
    }

    
    

    const resetForm = ()=>{
        setProperty({
        propertyImage: "",
        street : "",
        town : "",
        area : "",
        PostCode : "",
        NoBeds : "",
        NoBath : "",
        NoLivingRooms : "",
        askingPrice : "",
        })

    }


    
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="login-container-p">
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data" className='login-box-p'>
            <div className="a">
                <label htmlFor="street" className="screen-name-p">Street Name</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       name="street" 
                       value={property.street}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="street name"/>
                <label htmlFor="town" className="screen-name-p">Town</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       name="town" 
                       value={property.town}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="town"/>
                <label htmlFor="area" className="screen-name-p">Area</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       name="area" 
                       value={property.area}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="area"/>
                <label htmlFor="postcode" className="screen-name-p">Postcode</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       name="PostCode" 
                       value={property.PostCode}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="Postcode"/>
            </div>
            <div className="b">
                <label htmlFor="NoBeds" className="screen-name-p">Beds</label>
                <input type="number" 
                       name="NoBeds" 
                       value={property.NoBeds}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="Number of beds"/>
                <label htmlFor="NoBath" className="screen-name-p">Bathrooms</label>
                <input type="number" 
                       name="NoBath" 
                       value={property.NoBath}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="Number of bathrooms"/>
                <label htmlFor="NoLivingRooms" className="screen-name-p">Living Rroom</label>
                <input type="number" 
                       name="NoLivingRooms" 
                       value={property.NoLivingRooms}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="Number of living rooms"/>
                <label htmlFor="askingPrice" className="screen-name-p">Asking Price(£)</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       name="askingPrice" 
                       value={property.askingPrice}
                       onChange={onChange}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="£249,999"/>
                <label htmlFor="propertyImage" className="screen-name-p">Property Images</label>
                <input type="file" 
                       id="file"
                       filename="propertyImage" 
                       name="propertyImage"
                       onChange={onChangeFile}
                       className="form-control-p"
                       placeholder="Upload property images"/>
            </div>
            <div className="c">
                <button className="" 
                        type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
                
            </form>
            {message ? <Message message={message}/> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}


export default Properties
PropertyService.js==================================================
export default {
    getProperties : ()=>{
        return fetch('/user/properties')
                .then(response=>{
                    if(response.status !== 401){
                        return response.json().then(data => data);
                    }
                    else
                        return {message : {msgBody : "UnAuthorized",msgError : true}};
                },[]);
    },

    getAllProperties : ()=>{
        return fetch('/properties')
                .then(response=>{
                    if(response.status !== 202){
                        return response.json().then(data => data);
                    }
                    else
                        return {message : {msgBody : "Error",msgError : true}};
                },[]);
    },
  

    
    postProperty : property=>{
        return fetch('/user/property', {
            method : "post",
            body : JSON.stringify(property),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response=>{
            if(response.status !== 401){
                return response.json().then(data => data);
            }
            else
                return {message : {msgBody : "UnAuthorized"},msgError : true};
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Change your `onChangeFile`:

```
const onChangeFile = e =>{
   const formData= new FormData();
   formData.append('propertyImage', e.target.files[0]);
   setPropertyImage(formData)
}
```

2. Change call to `PropertyService`:

```
PropertyService.postProperty(property).then(data =>{
```

3. Change `body` in `postProperty` in `PropertyService` not to take `JSON.stringify()`:

```
body : property,
```

4. Uncomment `propertyImage` in `useState()`

Comment: Where would I implement this as I have tried a few things and still get the error. Do all the fields need to be processed with formData?

Comment: You can create one variable where you will store the selected file `event.target.files[0]`. And before the call to the beckend, you can just create the `formData` as in snippet above, and send that one to the beckend: `PropertyService.postProperty(property, formData).then(data =>{`. And not all fields need to be processed with `fromData`, only the file.

Comment: I have a new error now and It will not let me post anything. "POST http://localhost:3000/user/property 500 (Internal Server Error)
postProperty @ PropertyService.js:27"

Comment: can you edit the question with your change?

Comment: I have edited it, The error appears to come from the PropertyService and the OnSubmit section

Comment: can you try to `console.log()` both `property` and `formData` before the line that is sending them to the beckend?

Comment: property contains the details that I have inputted on the form, formData display an empty object

Comment: Wait... Are you using the same code as the code above? Because in a code above, `propertyImage` property in `useState` is commented.

Comment: I have removed the comment but it changes nothing

Comment: It means that `propertyImage` that you are putting in `formData` is empty. Check if you properly put the `event.target.files[0]` in `propertyImage`. Try to `console.log()` `propertyImage` before you put it to `formData`

Comment: When i console.log propertyImage, it displays the images that has been selected to be uploaded

Comment: Can you add in your question code where you implemented the `PropertyService`?

Comment: I have added the section

Comment: You are sending `property` and `formData` but in `postProperty` you are receiving only one parameter. Also you don't need `JSON.stringify(property)`. Just send data without `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: What would the other parameter be?

Comment: I updated my answer with refactor. Can you try it?

Comment: I'm afraid It still does not work, I get the error " POST http://localhost:3000/user/property 500 (Internal Server Error)
postProperty @ PropertyService.js:27
onSubmit @ Property.js:26"

Comment: After hours of playing about with it, If I reset the code to my original code and comment out the propertyImage: req.file.path under the backend post function it allows me to send all the data except the image. Any ideas why this is happening? I don't understand why it works fine using postman but not here!

Comment: Because you have to send an image with `formData` in order for `Multer` to parse it. If everything works now, can you `console.log` `property` inside the `postProperty()` to check if you have the `propertyImage` inside `property`. And can you add that in your question?

Comment: I have decided to refactor a lot of the code and put it in a new question. I need to be able to add multiple images and therefore thought that it would be better to refactor now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149507/uploading-images-will-upload-via-postman-but-nothing-else